# Cmake file to support C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile, build, cmake

I need to build and make sources, but this error appears:

```
error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
```

I saw in other topics that this is easily fix by changing flag in CMakeLists.txt to '-std=c++11', but there is no CMakelists.txt in build directory.

Can someone help me?

-- OBS: I'm on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: We're going to need more information. What command(s) do you use to build your sources?

Comment: mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. && make

Comment: cmake version 3.5.1

Comment: Then the CMakeLists.txt is in the parent folder of build (hence the `cmake ..`).

Comment: LS: CMakeCache.txt  CMakeFiles  cmake_install.cmake  Makefile

Comment: That's the contents of build, not of its parent folder. The parent folder will contain the CMakeLists.txt (if it didn't, your cmake call would fail).

Comment: there is no CMakeLists.txt in build or in sources folder

Comment: i need to flag -std=-c++11 but doesnt work, and i cant find this file to change manually

Comment: Check the **parent folder** of build. http://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/68042/parent-folder

Comment: parent fold of build is src (where is the sources) and there is no CMakeLists

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125747/discussion-between-mindriot-and-arnaldo-badin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest way to enable c++11 in your CMake project is to set the variable CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD in the main CMakeLists.txt.

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
```

You may also want to set CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS to off to use -std=c++11 instead of the default -std=gnu++11 with GCC extensions.

The variables and associated properties are documented here:

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/variable/CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD.html#variable:CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/variable/CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS.html